# Python selenium-webdriver error on send_keys

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am working on the website https://www.pnct.net/ for couple hours already. I still can not search the container on this website by webdriver.
Right now, my problem is I can not send the container number into the Chome. I can click the field by

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="top-section"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/label').click()
```

but below has error

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="top-section"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/label').send_keys('GAOU6723923')
```

I had try use find with same error

```py
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'md-textarea purple-textarea valid')
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//textarea[@class='md-textarea purple-textarea']").send_keys('GAOU6723923')
```

Also, please refrain from using such long xpaths in your code. The locators must be as relative as possible.

You may want to check this out and build your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.pnct.net/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Select Inquiry Type']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text() = 'Container Availability by Container']").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//textarea[@class='md-textarea purple-textarea']").send_keys('GAOU6723923')
```

One thing here: I have used `time.sleep` to quickly build the code, but ideally it is better if you use `WebdriverWait`